# What is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{r}{4r^2+1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{r}{4r^2+1}?$$

I have no clue how to do it.Any way to break this into telescoping sum?

Comment: it is infinity. your terms are larger than $C/r$ for some $C>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It diverges by comparison:$$\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{r}{4r^{2}+1} \ge \sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{5r} \to \infty$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n \displaystyle \frac{r}{4r^2+1} \geq \displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n \displaystyle \frac{r}{4r^2+r^2} = \displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n \displaystyle \frac{r}{5r^2} = \displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n \displaystyle \frac{1}{5r}$$

and $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \displaystyle \frac{1}{5r}$ diverges by the integral test (or whatever you use to prove the harmonic series diverges), so this series (of positive terms) also diverges by the comparison test.

So the limit of your series is $\infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: I think your first inequality is wrong.

Comment: Oh yes, typo, will change!